# MySQL master-master replication: "Lock wait timeout exceeded"

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

I am setting up master-master replication with MySQL.

Writes are done only to Master1. Master2 is slave of Master1 and is replicating perfectly. When I set Master1 as slave of Master2, I get lots of the following errors:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded
```

When I stop replicating on Master1 (with STOP SLAVE), the errors stop too.

What could cause this? I figured it could be some sort of circular replication loop. But why?